# How to check that no local traffic is routed via vpn to a remote server

Tags: vpn, vpnc

I have a simple VPN setup: as a client I connect to my office. To prevent that my local internet traffic is routed to the office I have checked the box:
"Use this connection only for resources on its network" and disabled the automatic checkbox.
I use Ubuntu 19.04 and vpnc

How can I check that no local traffic is routed to the office?

Comment: Have you checked `ip -4 route list` output to see what your routes are?  That will give you an idea what traffic is routed over the VPN and what isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a quite simple path:

- capture on the remote system with wireshark the traffic with the mentioned button disabled,
- on the local machine visit a webpage which is more or less rarely visited
- stop the capture and check if the just visited webpage is part of the capture: it should since all traffic should be routed via the vpn
- now enable the button
- start the capture again
- revisit the webpage from above
- stop the capture
- check the capture, now the webpage should not be in the capture, if so the button does what it is meant for

Answer (score 1):

The traceroute command might give you a hint as to which route the traffic is taking, e.g.:

```
traceroute www.google.com
```